# IE8 error on jQuery function "Expected identifier, string or number"

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, identifier

I am trying to wrap my head around this issue, but don't see what causes the error, I have following function that gets errors only in ie8 and due to this breaks all jQuery functionality as well as other JavaScript bits. (function is located inside app.js file)

```
function visitorAges(category, number) {
    // Ages for adults
    if (category == 'adult') {
        var arrayAges = ['18 - 20', '21 - 30', '31 - 40', '41 - 50', '51 - 60', '60 +'];
    }
    // Ages for children
    else if (category == 'child') {
        var arrayAges = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17];
    }
    // Populate related select menu with options    
    $('#visit_'+category+'_ages').empty();
        for (var i=1; i<=number; i++ ) {
            var $ageLabel = $('<label/>', {for: 'visit_'+category+'-'+i+'_age', text: category+' '+i});
            var $ageSelect = $('<select/>', {name: 'visit_'+category+'-'+i+'_age', id: 'visit_'+category+'-'+i+'_age', class: 'form-control'});
            $.each(arrayAges, function(index, value){
            $ageSelect.append($('<option/>', {text: value}));
            })
            $('#visit_'+category+'_ages').append($ageLabel, $ageSelect).fadeIn();
    }
} /* END visitorAges() */
```

The errors I get in IE8 console are as follows:

```
Expected identifier, string or number 'app.js, line 99 character 35'

var arrayAges = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17];
```

and

```
Expected identifier, string or number 'app.js, line 104 character 35'

var $ageLabel = $('<label/>', {for: 'visit_'+category+'-'+i+'_age', text: category+' '+i});
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you targeting?

Comment: @wicker95 2.1.3 for ie9 and above, 1.11.2 for ie8 and below, I had this thought as well, but after removing problematic function mentioned in question, everything worked, thus right jQuery is loaded

Comment: Which code line does throw the error?

Comment: Anything in here useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584249/javascript-vs-ie8-expected-identifier-string-or-number?

Comment: I bet that's what it is: you have an object property called `class`. I reckon if you put that in quotes you'll be golden. Best off quoting all your keys for consistency.

Comment: I'd wrap for, class, name etc. in quotes as IE may not like it.

Comment: @collapsar oh my bad, edited my question to show those lines

Comment: @LShetty thats what it was, you could post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I said in my comments, IE requires keywords to be wrapped in quotes when they are not used as keywords, such as the one below. Notice the keywords for, class etc.

```
var $ageLabel = $('<label/>', {for: 'visit_'+category+'-'+i+'_age', text: category+' '+i});
var $ageSelect = $('<select/>', {name: 'visit_'+category+'-'+i+'_age', id: 'visit_'+category+'-'+i+'_age', class: 'form-control'});
```

So, all we need to do is to wrap them as below which works in all browsers.

```
var $ageLabel = $('<label/>', {'for': 'visit_'+category+'-'+i+'_age', 'text': category+' '+i});
var $ageSelect = $('<select/>', {'name': 'visit_'+category+'-'+i+'_age', 'id': 'visit_'+category+'-'+i+'_age', 'class': 'form-control'});
```

P.S. I have wrapped all keys just to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Mh, I guess you need **String** in your array, not **Number**:

```
var arrayAges = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17'];
```

Also, you should (not necessary but prefered) to declare once your var **arrayAges** before the condition and affect it in your if/else.